# What’s another year to the Moroccans?

Tags: knowledge, cryptic-clues, sequence

Here are some rileys, which lead to a **thing**, or more properly a Thing, which will be happening, um, come December. So hear the joyous songs of rileys!

(Huh? Oh yes, yes… HOW DID I FORGET THAT?)

*Someone runs back on stage.*

Rileys? Oi never knew em! Cryptics!

Well, this is a history, so let’s begin. Seven sings to rule them all.

Of course, only one debut each time…

Any germ, step up, it'll mix you up! (7)

A Duke’s elected Master’s Right vertical displacement. (7, it shouldn’t be THAT unwieldy… and they’re only taller than the other one!)

A Brit’s Territorial Army is in! (7)

Neither way works for programmers. (6)

Some are in the spa. (5)

Let’s skip ahead a wee bit… to our main character!

More siroccos while the sire’s gone! (7)

Umm… they got canceled…

Then… uh… the velvet bull… but that’s right before our finale…

I šta čemo sad, I think… it’s all a blur…

AND HERE WE ARE, OUR FINALE…

**What’s our finale?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you get your head around the seemingly chaotic (!) text, there are enough clues within it to work out that our focus here should be on:

> the **Eurovision Song Contest**. The six 'cryptic clues' listed in the puzzle all resolve to the names of countries in the sequential order that they *debuted* in Eurovision, there is a mention of 'seven **sings** to rule them all', and the 'Thing' happening in December is the next instalment in the Eurovision calendar - the [Junior Eurovision Song Contest 2022](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junior_Eurovision_Song_Contest_2022).

Let's turn our attention first to what I shall refer to as 'cryptic-*esque* clues', since they don't all *quite* conform to true cryptic crossword norms.

*Any germ, step up, it'll mix you up! (7)*

> **GERMANY** - an anagram of ANYGERM. Germany took part in the very first Eurovision Song in 1956.

*A Duke’s elected Master’s Right vertical displacement. (7, it shouldn’t be THAT unwieldy… and they’re only taller than the other one!)*

*A Brit’s Territorial Army is in! (7)*

> I can't quite spot the full intention behind these clues, as they don't appear to follow regular cryptic crossword clue rules. Also, there appears to be an expectation from the puzzle text that there is only '*one debut each time*', suggesting one per year... However, the only 7-letter countries that debuted between 1956 and 1960 (the year of the next clue, as we shall see) are Denmark and Austria, who both debuted in 1957.
>
>  My suspicion is that first of these clues is intended to clue **DENMARK** and the second **AUSTRIA**, due to the prominent initials DEMR in the first, and selected letters of [T]e[R]r[I]tori[A]l in the second.

*Neither way works for programmers. (6)*

> **NORWAY**, debutants in 1960. Derived from [NOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOR_gate) + WAY.

*Some are in the spa. (5)*

> **SPAIN**, debutants in 1961. Formed from SPA plus IN, although this wordplay isn't technically suggested by the clue...

*More siroccos while the sire’s gone! (7)*

> **MOROCCO** - MOR(-esir)OCCO(-s). And this is the whole point behind the title of the puzzle - Morocco only ever participated in Eurovision once, in one year: 1980. (This was an interesting piece of trivia I had never realised before, so thanks to the OP for that!)

We're approaching the 'finale' now, but before that there is mention of a *velvet bull*. This is an allusion towards:

> the **SAN MARINO** [entry for the 2022 Eurovision contest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Marino_in_the_Eurovision_Song_Contest_2022), a song called *Stripper*, performed by Lauro, involving a moment where he rode upon a pink velvet mechanical bull. San Marino is the second-to-last country to have debuted in the contest (joint with Azerbaijan), back in 2008.

This means that our 'finale' likely revolves around...

> ...the country who has *most recently debuted in Eurovision*. Those not familiar with the contest may be surprised to learn that this is (the famously not-at-all-in-Europe nation of) **AUSTRALIA**! Which I suspect is the final answer to this puzzle...

Comment: Wow, chaotic, indeed. For what it's worth, I can imagine that rot13(Qraznex vf zvffcryyrq nf Qvaznex (vg'f Qvanznepn va Fcnavfu, sbe rknzcyr) naq jr unir Q + VA + Z.N. + E + hz, fbzrguvat. Iregvpny qvfcynprzrag pbhyq or L naq M, ohg V qba'g frr ubj vg pbhyq or X. Naq Nhfgevn _pbhyq_ unir NY (nezl fbzrguvat?) erzbirq sebz n sbezre Oevgvfu greevgbel.) Yeah, I'm not convinced.

Comment: Seven is a reference to the seven countries of the first Eurovision. But good job, it WAS the first one you mentioned, and you get a shiny, polished +1! "I šta čemo sad" is a reference to... well... if you watched Eurovision you would know...

Comment: Also @Stiv cryptic norms suck. See C. Chaos for an example of why chaos is better. It allows better cryptics because it allows you to be cleverer! Great finishing up makes a good-paying job... (4,3)

Comment: @someoneinexistence: !It allows better cryptics because it allows you to be cleverer!! It allows you to be smug. "I must be brilliant, no-one could solve my clue!" Yeah, because no-one can read your mind. If you want to be clever, write good clues that conforms to the rules, so that people can actually solve them. If you can't do that, use something else: rebus, flags, whatever.

Comment: @M Oehm I like cryptics being chaotic because that's how I like puzzles: the aha of connecting disparate things.

Comment: @someoneinexistence If you're not following the rules of cryptics, then you're *not writing cryptics* - you're writing something vaguely inspired by cryptics, but without any of the rules that make them fair to solve. I realize that you enjoy *writing* puzzles this way, but it doesn't make puzzles that are fun to *solve*. The puzzle just comes out as a bunch of nonsensical babbling, where we have to read your mind to figure out what parts to make vague associations with, and what parts to completely ignore. [...]

Comment: [...] I can't speak for other people, of course, but this is why I've avoided many of your puzzles - they seem like the same type of walls of "stream-of-consciousness" rambling. "Figure out what I was thinking while writing this", without making sure the task is *fair*, isn't a puzzle: it's a guessing game. And the process of interpreting "stream-of-consciousness" text isn't particularly fun.